# Why is D0 not flashing?

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, pic, mplab

I'm trying to flash D0, but D0 only stays on.  How do I fix this?

```
list r=dec

    include P16f684.inc

    __CONFIG _FCMEN_OFF & _IESO_OFF & _BOD_OFF & _CPD_OFF & _CP_OFF & _MCLRE_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _WDT_OFF & _INTOSCIO 

 Cblock 0x20 ; start of GPR

count ;

 endc ; This directive must be
 ; supplied to terminate the
 ; cblock list
;
 ;
; ----- main program --------------

 org 0x000 ; Hex address 0x000, the first
 ; program memory location
;
start BCF STATUS,RP0 ; Select Bank 0
;
 CLRF PORTA ; Initialize PORTA (all zeros)
;
 MOVLW 7 ; Load w with 7
 MOVWF CMCON0 ; Load CMCON0 with 7
 ; Turns off comparators
;
 BSF STATUS,RP0 ; Select Bank 1
;
 CLRF ANSEL ; Shut off ADC (digital I/O)
;
 MOVLW b'001111' ; Load w ? RA4 and RA5 outputs
 MOVWF TRISA ; copy w to TRIS PORTA
;
 BCF STATUS,RP0 ; Select Bank 0
;
Loop BSF PORTA,4 ; Make RA4 high -- D0 ON
;
 CALL Delay ; Goto the delay routine
;
 BCF PORTA,4 ; Make RA4 low -- D0 OFF
;
 CALL Delay ; Goto the delay routine
;
 GOTO Loop ; Do it again
;
;
Delay MOVLW 10 ; Decimal 10
 MOVWF count ; Initialize counter to 10
Repeat DECFSZ count,f ; Decrement counter
 GOTO Repeat ; If counter <> 0
 RETURN ; If counter = 0 (end delay)
;
 end
```

Comment: The requirement to have enough text, not just code, isn't something you should work around by filling with garbage.  Instead make a better [mcve] by describing how you're building/running this code and on what hardware or simulator.  And what you found when single-stepping with a debugger.

Comment: Have you checked that you're not just flashing it so fast that it looks solid on?  Or is your repeat loop broken so it gets stuck on the first call?

Comment: Sorry, I'm stressed.

Comment: I have no idea...Should I change Delay MOVLW 10; to something else?

Comment: circuit: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J3s_-Q1nHWVtfe_g7786bmp8Sfj66Uwd/view

Comment: PIC16F684: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AQ40wsfEcCOiz81Y9ZTv1WXucXkCTPI3/view

Comment: [edit] your question to add those details.  But keep in mind it needs to stand on its own; for your question to have use for future searchers it needs to be mostly self-contained so you need at least a summary of your external links.

Comment: I figured this out with a different way... but I still would like to know what is wrong this delay loop ...

Comment: Unless your clock speed is like 100Hz or something, only 10 loop iterations is probably so fast that the LED looks continuously on.  I don't know PIC assembly specifically so there might be bugs other than `10` being way too small; single-step it with a debugger to find out.

Comment: I tried 100, 1000,10000 loops, but it didn't work... I wonder if the code itself may cause the issue

Comment: Maybe.  **Use a debugger to single step your code.**  (In a simulator if not on real hardware).  That'll tell you if it gets stuck or not.  If not, anything more than 20 to 30Hz will visually blur into constant-on, although maybe less bright because of 50% duty cycle.  So for a non-nested loop at 1 iteration per 2 clocks (randomly made-up number), 10 Hz * 10000 * 2 = 200kHz max clock speed to stay under 10Hz.  You haven't posted enough details in the question to rule out too high a clock speed even if you loop does work.  (And I'm assuming that's a 16-bit counter...)

Comment: NotSoTechnical, The code you posted takes 74 instruction cycles to toggle the LED on then off. With the system oscillator at the default 4 MHz then the LED will flash on and off every 74 microseconds. For most human vision systems this interval is too brief to be perceived.